# C# - Unable to GetAssemblies from created domain

Tags: c#, applicationdomain

I created a new application domain and loaded 2 assemblies in to it (see code example below). However if I try to use `GetAssemblies` method I get exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAppDomains
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"D:\PROGRAMMING\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\bin\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe";
            String pathdll = @"D:\PROGRAMMING\ConsoleTestDll\ConsoleTestDll\bin\Debug\ConsoleTestDll.dll";
            AppDomain myDomain1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain1");
            //Create the loader (a proxy).
            var assemblyLoader = (SimpleAssemblyLoader)myDomain1.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(SimpleAssemblyLoader).Assembly.FullName, typeof(SimpleAssemblyLoader).FullName);

            assemblyLoader.LoadFrom(path);
            assemblyLoader.LoadFrom(pathdll);
            var currentDomainAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            var myDomainAssemblies = myDomain1.GetAssemblies(); //There is exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException

            Task.Run(() => myDomain1.ExecuteAssembly(path));
            //Finally unload the AppDomain.
            Console.ReadKey();
            AppDomain.Unload(myDomain1);
        }
        public class SimpleAssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
        {
            public void Load(string path)
            {
                ValidatePath(path);
                Assembly.Load(path);
            }
            public void LoadFrom(string path)
            {
                ValidatePath(path);
                Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            }
            private void ValidatePath(string path)
            {
                if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("path \"{0}\" does not exist", path));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which point do you get error? And, did you check the path which you pass into method? Is that path really correct and exists?

Comment: I got error there `var myDomainAssemblies = myDomain1.GetAssemblies(); //There is exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException` . Paths are corrects because there is ValidatePath method in SimpleAssemblyLoader and application is correctly started without this part of code.